# Why doesn't the code change the source of the image to the key of the object?

Tags: javascript, object

```js
//this is the "dictionary"

var imgdict = {
  "file:///C:/Users/tribl/Desktop/.program/in%20Arbeit/rating/1.jpg": 0,
  "file:///C:/Users/tribl/Desktop/.program/in%20Arbeit/rating/2.jpg": 0,
  "file:///C:/Users/tribl/Desktop/.program/in%20Arbeit/rating/3.jpg": 0,
  "file:///C:/Users/tribl/Desktop/.program/in%20Arbeit/rating/4.jpg": 0,
  "file:///C:/Users/tribl/Desktop/.program/in%20Arbeit/rating/5.jpg": 0,
  "file:///C:/Users/tribl/Desktop/.program/in%20Arbeit/rating/6.jpg": 0,
  "file:///C:/Users/tribl/Desktop/.program/in%20Arbeit/rating/7.jpg": 0,
  "file:///C:/Users/tribl/Desktop/.program/in%20Arbeit/rating/8.jpg": 0,
  "file:///C:/Users/tribl/Desktop/.program/in%20Arbeit/rating/9.jpg": 0,
};

//As mentioned, these functions add, or distract 1 from the values seen above

function plus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("imgs").src;
  imgdict.x = imgdict[x]++;
  console.log(imgdict);

  document.getElementById("imgs").src = images[counter % images.length];
  counter += 1;

  window.z = (Object.values(imgdict));
  z.pop(10);
  console.log(z);
}

function minus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("imgs").src;
  imgdict[x]--;
  console.log(imgdict);

  document.getElementById("imgs").src = images[counter % images.length];
  counter += 1;

  window.z = (Object.values(imgdict));
  z.pop(10);
  console.log(z);
}
//this function is supposed to select the key with the most "+1s" and use it as the source of the image

function winner() {
  //I think somethings wrong in this function but I am too new to know what exactly

  window.z = (Object.values(imgdict));
  z.pop(10);
  document.getElementById("top").src = imgdict[Math.max(z)];
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="mainBx">
    <div class="active">
      <figure class="imgCont">

        <!-- These buttons each give a key of the dictionary, either +1 or -1 -->

        <li onclick="plus()"></li>
        <li onclick="minus()"></li>
        <img src="1.jpg" id="imgs" class="imgs">
      </figure>
    </div>

    <div>
      <figure class="imgbox">

        <!-- I want to show this picture. -->

        <img src="" class="winnerimg" id="top">
      </figure>

      <!-- ...by clicking this button -->

      <figure class="top" onclick="winner()">
        1st place
      </figure>

      <!-- This is useless for now -->

      <figure class="rest">
        <p>2nd place</p>
        <p>3rd place</p>
        <p>4th place</p>
        <p>5th place</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please clarify the expected result. Even after watching the code i don't understand what should happen in the three event handlers.

Comment: its some kind of rating system of 9 images. When clicking "plus" or "minus" the value of the image currently shown is either subtracted by one or one is added. the function "winner" is turning only the values of the object "imgdict" into an array of numbers, of which the highest one is supposed to be displayed in another img tag. The problem is that the image with the highest value isnt showing up. In the console it shows the right path of the image but not the right image if you know what i mean. like documents/programming/xyz/undefined

Comment: I just need to know how to acces the objects key by its value

Comment: Why do you attach the var"z" to the window object? And what should be the var "images"? Since it is not defined it throws an "Uncaught ReferenceError"...

Comment: I answered your question. Please check it...

Answer (score 0):

First, i found some issues in your code:

- `imgdict[x]++` doesn't work -> use `imgdict[x] += 1` (the same for `--`)
- `pop()` has no param - it deletes always the last element
- `Math.max` has to be used for arrays with the spread operator `...`
- `src` depends on the path - since the path could change (for example local vs. server) it would be better to use a `data-id` in the `img` tag and as object keys

---

## Basic implementation

I presume that you want to show the image with the highest value. For example the fifth element in the object has the highest value (maybe 1) and you want to show the fifth image and not the first. Therefor you shouldn't use `imgdict[Math.max(z)]` because it gives you the value (maybe 1) and not the key (maybe for the fifth image). To get the key of the highest value you could create an array of all keys with `Object.keys()` and find the max-value-key with the `reduce()` method and an anonymous sort function.

```js
Object.keys(imgdict).reduce(function(a, b) { 
  return imgdict[a] > imgdict[b] ? a : b;
});
```

**Working example**

I deleted the parts that weren't necessary for the demonstration or didn't work, for example because `images` and `counter` aren't defined. I also replaced the (here not existing) images with loremflickr-pics.

```js
var imgdict = {
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 0,
  5: 1,  /* 1 for demonstration */
  6: 0,
  7: 0,
  8: 0,
  9: 0,
};

function plus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("imgs").dataset.id;
  imgdict[x] += 1;
}

function minus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("imgs").dataset.id;
  imgdict[x] -= 1;
}

function winner() {
  let winnerMaxKey = Object.keys(imgdict).reduce(function(a, b) { 
    return imgdict[a] > imgdict[b] ? a : b;
  });
  document.getElementById("top").src = 'https://loremflickr.com/140/100?random=' + winnerMaxKey;
  document.getElementById("top").dataset.id = winnerMaxKey;
  console.log(document.getElementById("top").src);
}
```

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.top {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="mainBx">
    <div class="active">
      <figure class="imgCont">
        <li onclick="plus()">+</li>
        <li onclick="minus()">-</li>
        <br>
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/140/100?random=1" data-id="1" id="imgs" class="imgs">
      </figure>
    </div>

    <div>
      <figure class="imgbox">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/140/100?random=5" data-id="5" class="winnerimg" id="top">
      </figure>

      <figure class="top" onclick="winner()">
        1st place
      </figure>

      <figure class="rest">
        <p>2nd place</p>
        <p>3rd place</p>
        <p>4th place</p>
        <p>5th place</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

---

## Advanced implementation

You could also add `prev`- and `next`-buttons and -functions.

**Working example:**

I replaced the `console.log()` with an output in a `span#current` or `span#first`. For example with:

```js
document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = 'Winner: ' + winnerMaxKey + ' / score: ' + imgdict[winnerMaxKey];
```

```js
var imgdict = {
  1: 0,
  2: 0,
  3: 0,
  4: 0,
  5: 1,  /* 1 for demonstration */
  6: 0,
  7: 0,
  8: 0,
  9: 0,
};

function plus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("imgs").dataset.id;
  imgdict[x] += 1;
  document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = 'Current: ' + x + ' / score: ' + imgdict[x];
}

function minus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("imgs").dataset.id;
  imgdict[x] -= 1;
  document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = 'Current: ' + x + ' / score: ' + imgdict[x];
}

function next() {
  var currentKey = parseInt(document.getElementById("imgs").dataset.id);
  var nextKey = currentKey < 9 ? currentKey + 1 : 1;
  document.getElementById("imgs").dataset.id = nextKey;
  document.getElementById("imgs").src = 'https://loremflickr.com/140/100?random=' + nextKey;
  document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = 'Current: ' + nextKey + ' / score: ' + imgdict[nextKey];
}

function prev() {
  var currentKey = parseInt(document.getElementById("imgs").dataset.id);
  var prevKey = currentKey > 1 ? currentKey - 1 : 9;
  document.getElementById("imgs").dataset.id = prevKey;
  document.getElementById("imgs").src = 'https://loremflickr.com/140/100?random=' + prevKey;
  document.getElementById("current").innerHTML = 'Current: ' + prevKey + ' / score: ' + imgdict[prevKey];
}

function winner() {
  let winnerMaxKey = Object.keys(imgdict).reduce(function(a, b) { 
    return imgdict[a] > imgdict[b] ? a : b;
  });
  document.getElementById("top").dataset.id = winnerMaxKey;
  document.getElementById("top").src = 'https://loremflickr.com/140/100?random=' + winnerMaxKey;
  document.getElementById("first").innerHTML = 'Winner: ' + winnerMaxKey + ' / score: ' + imgdict[winnerMaxKey];
}
```

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.top {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="mainBx">
    <div class="active">
      <figure class="imgCont">
        <li onclick="prev()"> < </li>
        <li onclick="minus()"> - </li>
        <li onclick="plus()"> + </li>
        <li onclick="next()"> > </li>
        <br>
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/140/100?random=1" data-id="1" id="imgs" class="imgs">
        <span id="current">Current: 1 / score: 0</span>
      </figure>
    </div>

    <div>
      <figure class="imgbox">
        <img src="https://loremflickr.com/140/100?random=5" data-id="5" class="winnerimg" id="top">
        <span id="first">Winner: 5 / score: 1</span>
      </figure>

      <figure class="top" onclick="winner()">
        1st place
      </figure>

      <figure class="rest">
        <p>2nd place</p>
        <p>3rd place</p>
        <p>4th place</p>
        <p>5th place</p>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```